# Nested per-field resolvers with Apollo Server

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm having some trouble building resolvers for something I'm working on. I'm doing something similar to what [this article](https://medium.com/paypal-engineering/graphql-resolvers-best-practices-cd36fdbcef55) suggests, where I have separate resolvers for each field within an entity. Here's a contrived version of my schema:

```
// schema.graphql

type Query {
  service: ServiceInfo
}

type ServiceInfo {
  configuration: ServiceConfiguration
  publicKey: PublicKey
  serverTokenInfo: ServerTokenInfo
}

type ServiceConfiguration {
  platformA: PlatformConfiguration
  platformB: PlatformConfiguration
  platformC: PlatformConfiguration
}
```

The deal is that `ServiceInfo` resolves each of its fields from a different datasource, which is fine. The difficulty that I'm encountering is that platformA, platformB, and platformC all resolve *their fields* from different datasources.

Here's the resolvers for what I have working at the moment:

```
// resolvers.js

export default {
  Query: {
    service: () => ({})
  },
  ServiceInfo: {     configuration: () => ({}),
    publicKey: (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getPublicKey(),
    serverTokenInfo: : (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getTokenInfo(),
  }
}
```

Now, I need to write a resolver for the `configuration`. I've tried a couple things:

```
// resolvers.js

export default {
  // ...
  ServiceInfo: {     configuration: () => ({}),
    // ...
    ServiceConfiguration: {
      platformA:  (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getConfig("A"),
      platformB:  (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getConfig("B"),
      platformC:  (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getConfig("C"),
    }
  }
}
```

This fails and tells me: `ServiceInfo.ServiceConfiguration defined in resolvers, but not in schema`. The next thing I tried was moving the `ServiceConfiguration` resolver to the top level:

```
// resolvers.js

export default {
  // ...
  ServiceInfo: {
    // ...
  }
  ServiceConfiguration: {
    platformA:  (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getConfig("A"),
    platformB:  (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getConfig("B"),
    platformC:  (_, args, ctx) => ctx.dataSources.service.getConfig("C"),
  }
}
```

...and it now fails and tells me that `ServiceConfiguration defined in resolvers, but not in schema` and I'm out of ideas. If anybody has some insight, I'd *really* appreciate it—I'm very stuck.

Comment: The resolver map cannot have nested types. It's just a map of type names, with each name mapping to a map of field names. So the latter approach *should* work. If you're seeing an error about `ServiceConfiguration` being defined in the resolvers but not in the schema -- and it *is* in fact in the schema -- there's something else wrong elsewhere in the code. For example, you might be importing your resolvers incorrectly.

Comment: Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57262117-gh8ik)